# Blazor template drawing a red line on the right side of sidebar

Tags: css, blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to draw a red line 3px wide on the right side of the `.sidebar` in Blazor default app but no matter what I do, it doesn't show up.  Css and example at the pic below.  What am I doing wrong please?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You not specifying the type of border. Here is the shorthand.

```
    .sidebar {
        border-right: 3px solid red;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  Worked.